# Why PulP returns negative values for blending problem while the lowBound is set to zero?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am using Python PulP to solve blending problem. The output is weird it returns negative values. What I am trying to

```py
from pulp import *
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_csv('feed.csv')

# Get required data from user
Ingredients = ['CORN', 'SBM', 'LIMESTONE', 'SALT', 'BONE_MEAL', 'PALM_OIL']


def cost():
    costs = {}
    for i in Ingredients:
        costs[i] = data.loc[data['feed'] == i, 'cost'].iloc[0]
    return costs

def protein():
    proteinPercent = {}
    for i in Ingredients:
        proteinPercent[i] = data.loc[data['feed'] == i, 'protein'].iloc[0]
    return proteinPercent

def energy():
    energyKcal = {}
    for i in Ingredients:
        energyKcal[i] = data.loc[data['feed'] == i, 'energy'].iloc[0]
    return energyKcal


def calcium():
    cal = {}
    for i in Ingredients:
        cal[i] = data.loc[data['feed'] == i, 'calcium'].iloc[0]
    return cal

def sodium():
    sod = {}
    for i in Ingredients:
        sod[i] = data.loc[data['feed'] == i, 'sodium'].iloc[0]
    return sod

def minimum():
    min = {}
    for i in Ingredients:
        min[i] = data.loc[data['feed'] == i, 'min'].iloc[0]
    return min

def maximum():
    max = {}
    for i in Ingredients:
        max[i] = data.loc[data['feed'] == i, 'max'].iloc[0]
    return max

# Initialize
costs = cost()
proteinPercent = protein()
energyKcal = energy()
cal = calcium()
sod = sodium()
L = minimum()
U = maximum()

# Create the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("Broiler Ration Formulation", LpMinimize)

# A dictionary called 'ingredient_vars' is created to contain the referenced Variables
ingredient_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Ingr",Ingredients, lowBound = 1, upBound = 60)

for i in Ingredients:
    prob += ingredient_vars[i] >= L[i]
    prob += ingredient_vars[i] <= U[i]


# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += lpSum([costs[i]*ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]), "Total Cost of Ingredients per can"

# The five constraints are added to 'prob'
prob += lpSum([ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) == 100, "Percentages Sum"
prob += lpSum([proteinPercent[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 19.0, "Min Protein Requirement"
prob += lpSum([proteinPercent[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) <= 21.0, "Max Protein Requirement"
prob += lpSum([energyKcal[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 3100.0, "Min Energy Requirements"
prob += lpSum([energyKcal[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) <= 3300.0, "Max Energy Requirements"
prob += lpSum([cal[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) <= 1.1, "Calcium Requirements"
prob += lpSum([sod[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) <= 0.2, "Sodium Requirements"


# The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
prob.solve()

# The status of the solution is printed to the screen
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])

# Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
for v in prob.variables():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)

# The optimised objective function value is printed to the screen    
print ("Total Cost of Ingredients per feed= ", value(prob.objective))
```

```py
File feed.csv content
feed    min max cost    energy  protein calcium sodium
BONE_MEAL   0   10  0.7 1600    0   30.32   1
CORN    0   60  0.5 3350    9.4 0.05    0
.
.
.
```

Some of the ouput variables are negatives:

```
Status: Infeasible

Ingr_BONE_MEAL = 1.0

Ingr_CORN = 37.862563

Ingr_FISH_MEAL = 1.0

Ingr_LIMESTONE = -0.81506256

Ingr_PALM_OIL = 60.0

Ingr_SALT = -0.0475

Ingr_SBM = 1.0

Total Cost of Ingredients per Feed =  32.988153372
```

I searched for possible solution but could not find any explanation or maybe my code wrong but cant figure out what went exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you add to you LpProblem instance will always be the objective function as described in [the PuLP documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html#problem-description). The order you have currently in your code is:

```
for i in Ingredients:
   prob += ingredient_vars[i] >= L[i]
   prob += ingredient_vars[i] <= U[i]


# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += lpSum([costs[i]*ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]), "Total Cost of Ingredients per can"
```

Your problem instance's objective function is `ingredient_vars[i] >= L[i]` which is non sensical.

The correct way is to add the objective function part before your constraints ,like so:

```
# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += lpSum([costs[i]*ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]), "Total Cost of Ingredients per can"

for i in Ingredients:
   prob += ingredient_vars[i] >= L[i]
   prob += ingredient_vars[i] <= U[i]
```

a good way to do the debugging of your linear program is to use the `prob.writeLP('blendingprob')` method which writes out an .lp file that shows the actual linear program

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have an `Infeasible` solution, which is what you have here. Since the solution is infeasible, pulp just throws out a solution, under which some of the constraints may be violated. You need to find out which of your constraints is incompatible with the others and change them. Perhaps you need to widen your calorie range, for instance.